# How to secure a window well cover to concrete and siding

Tags: concrete, drill, siding, well, cover

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to secure a plastic window well cover to our house, and the cement window well (if needed). My dad will help me if I can instruct him what to do. The one tool we don’t have is a hammer drill, but we could borrow one if needed.

I want to prevent water from coming in (not currently an issue), and prevent my daughter from falling in. I was advised to put window well covers on when we bought the house mostly.

The examples I see online do not have siding above the window, and most window wells seem to be made of metal. I don’t think the metal clips some use would work with cement. Of note, this is the only cover I can find that will fit unless we custom order one. Our house is old, from 1940.

Would we drill into the siding and concrete? And how would we secure it?

[image]

Comment: May have to get a custom made cover that will fit under the siding attach using masonry screws or concrete caulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might just **fasten some chain to the bubble and anchor it in the soil**. This will deflect water without any trouble and will add some measure of safety for small children.

How you do so depends on the nuances of fitment, but I'd drill holes in the bottom flange where appropriate and attach light chain, then attach something like a bit of fencing to the other end. Embed that in the soil and voila. You could put quick disconnects on the top end for easy removal.

Comment: Could hammer some stainless steel tubing/pipe into the ground (use a wood block to hammer against the top do you don't deform it too much) and fasten a stainless chain to the top of the tubing.  Or just bolt the flange of the well cover to the top of the tubing...I don't really see a need for a chain.

Answer (score 1):

I would not anchor anything into the siding.

Add an angle bracket to each side and anchor those to the concrete. You don't need a hammer drill. A good quality masonry bit will drill through the concrete and allow you to install some plastic anchors.

( Made some yellow marks on a pic to indicate the areas where brackets could be anchored)

If you want the whole dome sealed, that's another issue that would have to be addressed with caulk and flashing.

[image]

Comment: If you're referring to the window wall by "concrete", that's somewhat fragile and likely to spall.

Comment: Is that an egress window (i.e. finished basement)?  If so, you probably can't put anything permanent there as it would need to be easily pushed out without any tools in case an emergency exit is needed.  It's hard to tell from the picture the scale of the window, but it sure looks big enough to be an egress size.

Comment: @RMDman- question- is drilling into siding usually not recommended? Is it just a poor anchor?

Comment: @milwrdfan- the basement is technically “finished” but whoever did it did a lousy job (no insulation in the walls, who knows what else). So we don’t use it much at this time. I’ll post a better picture I just took. It’s not an egress window. It’s a sliding basement window, I guess if someone was short and skinny they could probably fit though it. There’s a flight of about 8 steps from the basement that lead up to a side door and landing.

Comment: @Alyn167,  Drilling and anchoring into the siding opens it up to water infiltration, even if sealed.  Over time that one or two small holes can cause a big issue with rotted wood and mold.  My thought, just don't do it.